# Replace variable names in column

Tags: regex, pandas, lambda

I have a column with names and I want to group into three different names shown in the column name Group

```
Col1          Group

Gbx stage PS -  1st
Gbx PS stage -  1st
Gbx 2nd -     2nd
2nd Gbx -     2nd
Gbx Iss -     2nd
stage Gbx PS -  1st
Gbx 3rd Hss - 3rd
HSS Gbx     - 3rd
Gbx HSS     - 3rd
```

The issue is that the names in the column can appear in different forms but I want them to divide into the three groups I showed.

I have tried

```
df.loc[df['Col1'].str.contains("Gbx 1st PS",na = False),'Component'] = '1st'
```

But I would like to use somehting more general by looking for string with "1st", "PS" patterns and grouping into same group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use double [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
m1 = df['Col1'].str.contains("ps", na = False, case=False)
#it seems one condition is not neccesery, so remove a bit unclear m2
#m2 = df['Col1'].str.contains("2nd",na = False, case=False)
m3 = df['Col1'].str.contains("hss", na = False, case=False)

df['new'] = np.where(m1, '1st', np.where(m3, '3rd', '2th'))
print (df)
           Col1 Group  new
0  Gbx stage PS   1st  1st
1  Gbx PS stage   1st  1st
2       Gbx 2nd   2nd  2th
3       2nd Gbx   2nd  2th
4       Gbx Iss   2nd  2th
5  stage Gbx PS   1st  1st
6   Gbx 3rd Hss   3rd  3rd
7       HSS Gbx   3rd  3rd
8       Gbx HSS   3rd  3rd
```

Solution with 3 conditions:

```
m1 = df['Col1'].str.contains("ps", na = False, case=False)
m2 = df['Col1'].str.contains("2nd", na = False, case=False)
m3 = df['Col1'].str.contains("hss", na = False, case=False)

df['new'] = np.where(m1, '1st', np.where(m2, '2nd', np.where(m3, '3rd', 'nothing match')))
print (df)
           Col1 Group            new
0  Gbx stage PS   1st            1st
1  Gbx PS stage   1st            1st
2       Gbx 2nd   2nd            2nd
3       2nd Gbx   2nd            2nd
4       Gbx Iss   2nd  nothing match
5  stage Gbx PS   1st            1st
6   Gbx 3rd Hss   3rd            3rd
7       HSS Gbx   3rd            3rd
8       Gbx HSS   3rd            3rd
```